# NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

I'm calling a controller that appears but after a while when I call back, I get this error:

> 2017-02-28 16:43:53.858 VoxInfra[38864:7593572] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)' with name 'TrackViewController''
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107085d4b **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010677e21e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00000001070ef2b5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197     3   UIKit
>
>   0x0000000103391bd2 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 507   4
>
>   UIKit                               0x00000001031259c5
>   -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386   5   UIKit                               0x00000001031262e7 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177   6   UIKit
>
>   0x000000010312661c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201   7
>
>   UIKit                               0x0000000103126e70
>   -[UIViewController view] + 27     8   UIKit                               0x00000001039e76a4 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController
>   _setPresentedViewController:] + 87    9   UIKit                               0x0000000103101702 -[UIPresentationController
>   initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 141  10 
>   UIKit                               0x0000000103139e97
>   -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3956     11  UIKit                               0x000000010313d26b
>   -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 530   12  UIKit                               0x000000010313cd51
>   -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179  13  VoxInfra                            0x0000000102dcd991
>   -[MainViewController controllerTrace:] + 209  14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070235ec
>   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 12   15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070234eb
>   _CFXRegistrationPost + 427    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107023252 **_CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50     17 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106fe6282
>   -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 2018  18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106fe531b
>   _CFXNotificationPost + 667    19  Foundation                          0x000000010514381b -[NSNotificationCenter
>   postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66   20  VoxInfra
>
>   0x0000000102dd2535 __36-[MainViewController
>   showMenuDroite]_block_invoke.658 + 101    21  VoxInfra
>
>   0x0000000102de3a9b __33-[CHTumblrMenuView buttonTapped:]_block_invoke
>   + 59  22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b3520cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8     23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b32e16c _dispatch_continuation_pop + 1091    24 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b3431de
>   _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 195     25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b33bd79 _dispatch_source_invoke + 1098   26 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b332afc
>   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1006  27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107049e49 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
>   + 9   28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010700f37d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010700e884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420   30  GraphicsServices
>   0x00000001082e5a6f GSEventRunModal + 161  31  UIKit
>   0x0000000102f84c68 UIApplicationMain + 159    32  VoxInfra
>   0x0000000102e3547f main + 111     33  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010b39e68d start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Check the name of your xib, and check if is there in your boundle resources, this should be the problem

Comment: No mame is good If I click on button to see ok but after several minutes click = crash

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: @JHT check using this code that your xib name is ok        `let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: self.getNibName(), ofType: "nib")
        debugPrint(path)`if print a path then is ok

Comment: I just tried again. And I have the impression that this problem was a sqlite I closed too many times the base.
But what connection?

Comment: Can you share a your piece of problematic code?, to see what is happening?

Comment: The problem was simply that I was closing and open sqlite when drawing the location of the user. This caused a problem in the application and the controllers after 30 minutes were more recognized. But I can not say.